# XML Viewer & Highlighter

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Below is xml file shown from google chrome.

[image: XML]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/v8vyqq1obtol22b/xml.png

I want to show xml file as like as that, but with highlight (As shown in the image, "Extractive Summarization" is highlighted in blue). Is there some library/plugin (php/javascript) to do that?

Thanks

Comment: @ParthThakkar highlight some words. As shown in the image, "Extractive Summarization" is highlighted in blue.